# Wpf Prevent Combobox Popup Close When Clicking Empty Spaces On Popup

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a combobox which I edited its control template.

If I press checkbox in combobox, popup doesn't close. But if I click borders or empty spaces in popup, popup closes. How can I prevent this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please post your control template. Keep in mind that we need a [mcve].

Comment: Reformat the text

Answer (score 0):

Combobox got no dedicated property to prevent this behaviour but in your case should setting of `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` should work. Now clicking on the line will select/deselect the checkbox and the drop down menu will stay opened.

Full example:

```xml
<ComboBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <CheckBox Content="1" />
    <CheckBox Content="2" />
    <CheckBox Content="3" />
    <CheckBox Content="4" />
    <CheckBox Content="5" />
    <CheckBox Content="6" />
</ComboBox>
```